# UITableView interFearing with UIPageControl on UIScrollView

Tags: xml, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a UIScrollView, UIPageControl and a UITableView all on the same page with parsed data from my server. The tableview and scrollview are parsing from different xml's so all is well there, but if I am on page 2-3-4-or 5 of my paging scrollview and touch the tableview the UIPageControl shows it moves back to page 1 and the information on page 2-3-4-5 change to page 1. Is it possible to tell the tableView that it has nothing to do with the scrollview or page indicator?

The code is necessary to see most of the page so I attached I link to pastie.org

http://pastie.org/2265484

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!